# How to resume a terminal with subprocess python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, terminal, subprocess

I am working with the subprocess module in Python. I am trying to run a series of terminals to automate a process.

To break it down:
I am suppose to have 3 terminals open to run a set of commands
like so:

```
Terminal 1: `cd src` -> `./run_script.sh`

Terminal 2: cd data -> `python prepare_data.py`

Terminal 3: `cd src` -> `./do_something.sh` #runs some docker container

Terminal 4: `cd src` -> `./do_another.sh`

Terminal 3: `./another_bash.sh`
```

To automate this the following:

```
class AutomateProcesses:
    
    def run_terminal_1(self):
        subprocess.call('./run_script.sh', shell=True, cwd='../src')
    
    def run_terminal_2(self):
        subprocess.call('python prepare_data.py', shell=True, cwd='../../data')
    
    def run_terminal_3(self):
        subprocess.call('./do_something.sh.sh', shell=True, cwd='../src')
    
    def run_terminal_4(self):
        subprocess.call('./do_another.sh', shell=True, cwd='../src')
```

How do I get back to terminal 3 to run the command?

Comment: Why don't you just create another sub-process and just run it as the 5th command?

Comment: the terminal 3 is a docker container and needs to ran there

Comment: "Go back to terminal 3 to run the command" -- what does that sequence of words even _mean_?

Comment: BTW, there is absolutely no reason to use `shell=True` in any of your examples. Every single one of those commands would be better off with the default `shell=False` (though for the `python prepare_data.py` example, the command would become `['python', 'prepare_data.py']`). Using `shell=True` makes your commands start _two_ shells -- the first one `sh -c ./run_script.sh`, and the second one started by `./run_script.sh`, depending on its shebang. (If it fails without `shell=True`, that means either permissions are wrong or the file _has_ no shebang; both are things that can and should be fixed)

Comment: Anyhow -- if you're using Docker correctly, you tell it what command to run _when you start the container_. Having the container start an interactive shell when what you want is it to run a command noninteractively is an example of using Docker badly. Don't do that: tell Docker what you want it to start, and let it _just do that itself_.

Comment: (Also, using `.sh` extensions on filenames of executables is not great. What happens if you want to rewrite one of those scripts in Python -- are you going to rename them and then need to change all the callers? Just like you run `pip` instead of `pip.py`, and `ls` instead of `ls.elf`, your `do_another` should just be named `do_another` with no `.sh`; see https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/ for an essay on the topic, or http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/.sh with the history of the relevant #bash factoid to show historical consensus).

Comment: Anyhow -- if you _really do_ want to interact with "terminal 3"'s stdin and stdout, you'll need to switch from `subprocess.call()` to `subprocess.Popen()`, and set `stdin=PIPE` at a minimum. If you want to watch stdout or stderr, you'll need to shunt those through pipes as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to run several commands on a "terminal" (actually you don't see any terminal), it is just a sub-process that runs a shell.

I use the tool called pexpect (https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html), it has the Windows-variant wexpect (https://pypi.org/project/wexpect/).

Below is the code sample, using the child variable, you can keep the "terminal" and send commands to it.

```
import pexpect
# log file to capture all the commands sent to the shell and their responses
output_file = open('log.txt','wb')

# create the bash shell sub-process
child = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash', logfile=output_file)
child.stdout = output_file
child.expect(bytes('>', 'utf-8'))
# make sure you use the pair (sendline() and expect()) to wait until the command finishes
child.sendline(bytes('ls', 'utf-8'))
child.expect(bytes('>', 'utf-8'))

child.sendline(bytes('echo Hello World', 'utf-8'))
child.expect(bytes('>', 'utf-8'))

output_file.close()
```